# Coluna não encontrada ao realizar SUM

Tags: java, sql

Estou desenvolvendo o sistema para uma escola.

Preciso criar a parte de férias.

Para isso preciso somar a quantidade de dias já lançados para que por ano não sejam lançados mais de 30 dias por funcionário.

Para isto vi que existe a função SUM do SQL

Contudo fica dando erro de coluna não encontrada.

Já chequei e o nome da coluna está idêntico.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que houve?

```
public void getSomaQuantidadeFerias(String rf, String exercicio) { ArrayList<Integer> total = new ArrayList<Integer>();
try {

        Connection con = new FabricaConexao("administracao").abrirConexao();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select sum(quantidade_dias) from ferias_alunos WHERE rf =? AND exercicio ?");

        stmt.setString(1, rf);
        stmt.setString(2, exercicio);

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
        total.add(rs.getInt("quantidade_dias"));
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < total.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(total.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println(total);

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }

    catch (SQLException sql) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deu ruim");
        sql.fillInStackTrace();
        System.out.println(sql.getLocalizedMessage());

        sql.printStackTrace();
    }
```

## Erro:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.3 Column not found: quantidade_dias
at control.CrtTelaAdministracao.getSomaQuantidadeFerias(CrtTelaAdministracao.java:1008)
at view.TelaFeriasA$2.actionPerformed(TelaFeriasA.java:418)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)UCAExc:::4.0.3 Column not found: quantidade_dias

at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Olá Josi, está faltando um espaço aqui ferias_alunosWHERE.

Comment: Arrumei, mas não resolveu o problema :(

Comment: Não está faltando um operador em: "AND exercicio ?"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altere a sua query para:

`select sum(quantidade_dias) as quantidade_dias from ferias_alunos WHERE rf =? AND exercicio ?`

O código `rs.getInt("quantidade_dias")` procura por um resultado cujo nome da coluna é `quantidade_dias`.
Da forma como está a sua query original, ela conta quantos registros existem, mas não nomeia o nome da coluna de resultado, por isso que você recebe a mensagem de erro de coluna não encontrada.

Comment: Deu certo!

Muito obrigada :D

Comment: @Josi Favor ler [como aceitar respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)